# Dereferencing Iterator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using std::string;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string s("some string");
    
    
      *s.begin() = toupper(*s.begin());
      
   
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
      
}
```

And the result is:

Some string

Why *s.begin() have to be used ?
Why I cannot just use s.begin() ? like:

```
s.begin() = toupper(s.begin());
```

Why the dereferencing operator * have to be used infront of an iterator ?

In the book C++ prime FIFTH EDITION P.107 , it  said we dereference that iterator to pass that character to toupper and to return the upper letter S to the original string.

But still I don't get it, why we cannot use the s.begin()  directly.
Isn't pointer just to save memory ?

Comment: Iterators are rather similar to pointers, but if `s.begin()` would be a pointer then you could also not assign a character to it, you also would have to dereference it.

Comment: "Isn't pointer just to save memory ?" no. Not at all. Its surprising why this misconception is so persistent.

Comment: The iterator cannot be a character or reference to it because then incrementing it would give e.g. 'B' instead of 'A', instead of the next character in the string. Of course one could user-define assignment and a conversion to `char` but that has perhaps unexpected side effects, and potentially introduces ambiguities (what is it that you want to increment?). Instead, `operator*()` is introduced that is trivial to implement, provides a clear, unambiguous API, solves all the user needs and involves only a minimum of additional (and quite intuitive) wordiness on the user side.

Comment: you can implement an iterator, then everything will be clear. It has been implement in the book if I remember it right.

Comment: Additionally, I should perhaps add, making `operator*()` the standard way to obtain a reference to the data element from an iterator into a container leaves the possibility open for the library implementor to simply typedef the iterator as a pointer for containers with contiguous data layout, like std::vector. Increment, decrement, comparison and member access are then already provided by the language without a single line of code.

Comment: For the first character, you could use [s.front()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) instead of `*s.begin()`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you'd be using a pointer:

```
 string s("some string");
 auto ptr = s.data();     // pointer to first character
```

Then you still need to dereference it before you can assign a character:

```
 *ptr = 'X';
```

Pointers add a level of indirection. A pointer is not the thing it points to. You have to dereference a pointer to access the pointee. With respect to that iterators are the same. An iterator into a string is not the character, though you can access the character via the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation about [std::string](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) you can see the prototype of `begin()` which is `iterator begin()`, it returns an `iterator`.

The prototype of `toupper()` is
`int toupper ( int c );`. It returns an `int` and accepts an `int`

Here you are tyring to assign an int (returned from `toupper()`)  to an iterator (returned from `s.begin()`). And you are passing an iterator to `toupper()` which accepts an `int`.

```
s.begin() = toupper(s.begin()); // iterator = int(iterator)
```

If you dereference the iterator it will return the reference of the value it points to. (`char&`)

```
*s.begin() = toupper(*s.begin()); // int = int(char)
```

Keep in mind that you are using references with iterators and not pointer directly.

Comment: The final comment should really be something like `char = int(char)`

Answer (score -1):

An iterator is a pointer that helps looping trough an object. In this case s.begin() is a pointer, so in order to access it's value you have to dereference it with "*".

Comment: "An iterator is a pointer " possibly yes, generally no